# Rails query all records whose all associated record has nil or some specific value in some specific fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models with a `has_many` and `belongs_to` relations:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

How do I find all those Parents whose all children have nil value in some specific field.

Answer (score 0):

Can you join the child table and then check for your `attribute_to_test` being nil?

`@nillish_parents = Parent.joins(:children).where("child.attribute_to_test IS ?", nil)`

```
@nillish_parents.each do |p|
    p.name
end
```

Answer (score -1):

'All children have a condition' is generally much harder!  I'm sure there's some way to do it with a complicated joins, but the easier ruby way is to do something like the following:

```
parents = []
Parent.includes(:children).find_each do |parent|
  parents.push(parent) if parent.children.collect{|child| child.field.nil?}.reduce(:&)
end
```

Comment: It's not particularly efficient, since it contains N + 1 problem. I would rather take some time and develop SQL solution in this case.

Comment: Yep I definitely agree it's not optimally efficient though but sometimes legibility is true efficiency :)  There are definitely slippery slopes you could go down where you attempt to joins together all children and end up with an O(n * m) despite being one db query

Comment: also @MarekLipka shouldn't the includes solve the N+1 problem?

Comment: No, since you create new sql query explicitly in each iteration.

Comment: right okay we can do this trickery then in ruby. I'll fix it up!